# How to execute "delete if there is a database named ‘Ebook’" in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
1 DROP DATABASE EBook
2 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysdatabases
3    WHERE name='EBook');
4
5 create database EBook
6 on
7 (
8 name='EBook',
9 filename='e:\\DB\EBook.mdf',
10 filegrowth=10%,
11 size=10
12 )
13 log on
14 (
15 name='EBook_log',
16 filename='e:\\DB\EBook_log.ldf',
17 filegrowth=10%,
18 size=10
19 )
```

Even if I use the

```
DROP DATABASE EBook SELECT * FROM sysdatabases WHERE name='EBook';
```

in the first sentence
I still have to report an error on the sixth line.

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiBVb.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cunm.png)

Comment: Why don't you drop the database if it is there it will be dropped; if it isn't there it will not drop

Comment: I totally agree with you, if I just want to delete the database. But can I acquire some knowledge while completing the task?

Comment: yes it returns an error if DB not exists; But if you use If Exists It will not show any error if DB was not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DROP DATABASE (or TABLE or FUNCTION or whatever) doesn't have a WHERE clause, but you can do:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS EBook;
```

Comment: It shows an error--"if" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF,";"

Comment: Forgive, you mean...?

Comment: That's a weird error, are you sure you had the if exists before that database name?

Comment: If you execute the request `select version();`, what is returned?

Comment: `DROP DATABASE EBook IF EXISTS EBook

create database EBook
on
(
name='EBook',
filename='e:\\DB\EBook.mdf',
filegrowth=10%,
size=10
)`

Comment: It may not be clear, but the first line should be the same as what you said

Comment: No.  You need EBook _after_ `if exists`, not before.  And you need a semicolon between EBook and create database

Answer (score 1):

Try this to drop table

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS EBook;
```

Comment: It shows an error--"if" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF,";"